# How to store array in column family

Tags: cassandra

I have a few specific data set which are related to each other. I need to store them in on column.

How do I create column family for store array or Collections? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PlayOrm for cassandra you just do

```
 @NoSqlEmbedded
 private List<String> stuff;
```

and it does it for you.

If you are doing it yourself, you just convert it to bytes and store it.  Be careful though.  There are situations like server 1 and server 2 read the value a,b,c and server 1 adds d and server 2 adds e.  If you don't do the stuff PlayOrm does for you and both servers write back, you end up with a,b,c,d OR a,b,c,e.  With the above in PlayOrm, you end up with a,b,c,d,e when both servers write back.

If you want to do the same as PlayOrm it is wiser to store each element in it's own column so the writes are independent and do not blow each other away but maybe you are ok with that?

EDIT: PlayOrm takes a List of a, b, c, d and treats it more like a Set so every one is unique.  Now, let's say two servers using PlayOrm do a write.

One server writes out
stuff:a=null, stuff:b=null, stuff:c=null

Second server writes out
stuff:a=null, stuff:b=null, stuff:d=null

If you read the above back in, you end up with a, b, c, d.  If you did this and wrote to a ONE column, the last server wins, but in this strategy the results are merged.  This is called composite column names where we store the values in the column name instead of the value field.

Just more info if you are interested..... In PlayOrm, you can create an entity like so

```
 @NoSqlEntity
 public class Entity {
    @NoSqlId
    private String id;
    @NoSqlEmbedded
    private List<String> stuff = new ArrayList<String>();
 }
```

and then you can save it like so

```
 NoSqlEntityManager mgr = ...
 mgr.put(someEntity);
 mgr.put(otherEntity);
 mgr.flush();  //here it is all actually written together
```

The flush is also nice since if you have an exception in any of your code NONE of it is written protecting you a little more from data corruption in your nosql store.

So PlayOrm will basically translate every instance of your Entity to a row in the noSql store.  You can look through the playorm feature list here

https://github.com/deanhiller/playorm#playorm-feature-list

Basically, it can't really be JPA as it takes advantage of lots of new noSql patterns JPA does not have.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "the stuff PlayOrm does for you"? Do you just mean setting a consistency level for the write?

Answer (score 1):

Why not create a column for each list element ?

for example 
array = [a, b, c, d]

```
col name   col value
---------------------
array:0  | a
array:1  | b
array:2  | c
array:3  | d
```

Comment: not so good if you have two servers and both read the row in and both write the row....now you have a problem....if both servers decide to use array:4 as the next spot and one writes BBB and one writes CCC, then the last one wins and you lose some data.  See the other answer on this post for a better way of doing it but it requires you want to save a set of unique values.